# compiled PDF suddenly broken

Tags: fonts, pdf, auxiliary-files, missing

I've been writing on a document for weeks without problems, now suddenly the compiled pdf has pages missing, SOME fonts in titles and formulas are weird (not all), pictures have random colored bars at the bottom and I get an error message when opening the pdf that "the embedded font "BADIHL+CMSS17" could not be extracted. Some Symbols might not be represented correctly."

I did not change any packages or use a command I hadn't before when it happened first.
I might have had a main.tex file open from another dokument in a different folder while compiling, but I am not sure.

Sometimes when I delete the .aux files it works for a single compilation. But after changing nothing and recompiling it breaks again.

I am using MikTeX with TeXstudio.
I have attached some screenshots of the correct and broken versions.
I am not a TeX veteran and have no idea where the bug might come from and am glad for any help I get.

Thanks in advance.

Correct version of a list:

[image: correct version]

Broken Version of a list as seen in the TeXstudio viewer (in adobe reader the broken text is missing):

[image: broken version]

Correct Version of a Formula:

[image: Correct version]

Broken Version of a Formula as seen in the TeXstudio viewer (in adobe reader the broken text is missing):

[image: broken version]

Correct version of an image:

[image: Correct version]

Broken version of an image:

[image: Broken version]

Correct Version of a page:

[image]

Broken version of a page (missing completely):

[image]

Edit:
It seems to be a problem with Texstudio. With TeXworks on the same PC or TeXstudio on other PCs it works just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm doubtful anyone will be able to debug this with the information you've given.  I would recommend making a copy of everything, and in that copy work through the steps in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497 to narrow down the problem.

Comment: try to make a smaller example and then show the log-file, most importantly the end with the font setup. And check if the pdf is also broken in other pdf viewer.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but since I found out that it works fine with other editors I will not go through the trouble of problem solving or creating a MWE.